# Workbench Errors. Is anyone else having an issue?

Tags: salesforcedx, workbench

Anyone else having workbench issues? Since yesterday whenever I try to do something I get redirected to a Heroku Error screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears broken. Not much we can do about it, though. Either Salesforce will fix it, or not. That said, you can always clone it and run a private instance if you want to. I've got one for myself, it's pretty easy to set up.